# Poem "口占" by 區越

Tags: translation, classical-chinese, poetry

I've found this beautiful poem "口占" by 區越 (Ming dynasty) on the internets:

> 共酌小亭下
>   詩新酒倍濃
>   閑花爭兩岸
>   醉眼不朦朧

I wasn't able to find much information other that that it's from Ming dynasty...

A good translation was also given, but I'd like to clarify a few details.
(This original translation is not in english, so I'll have to translate it as well, sorry if my translation of the translation is not very good)

1. `詩新酒` the original translation is *new rhymes and wine* but shouldn't it be the other way around - *rhymes and new wine*? In modern chinese an adjective precedes a noun, probably in Ming times it was not so?
2. `倍濃` in the original translation *they suit each other well*, shouldn't it be like *they make each other more intense*?
3. `閑花爭兩岸` in the original *flowers filled both banks so carelessly*, I'd like to clarify what is the closest translation of `爭` here? In modern chinese it has a meaning *to struggle, to dispute*, so is it that flowers *compete with each other* over which one blooms better or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 詩新酒倍濃

i would chop the verse into "詩新" & "酒倍濃".

roughly, the freshly made poem (詩新) made alcoholic drink (酒) much (倍) stronger (濃)

> 閑花爭兩岸

well, wild flowers do not exist alone in real, natural environment, they are in groups, thousands of them blossom together at the same time, in the same place. so, for individual bud, it strive (爭) for bees' pollination.

have fun :)

Answer (score 3):

> 共酌小亭下 means: " drink together under a small pavilion"

(1.)(2.) It is not '詩新酒.' It is '詩新(poem is new) 酒倍濃(wine is doubly strong) '

```
In modern Chinese an adjective precedes a noun, 
probably in Ming times it was not so?
```

*Adjective can be placed before or after the noun in both ancient and modern Chinese.

For example:

- 詩新 (poem is new) / 新詩(new poem)
- 酒濃(wine is strong) / 濃酒 (strong wine)
- 他人蠢(he as a person, is foolish) / 他是個蠢人(he is a **foolish** person)

> 詩新酒倍濃 means: " when enjoying a new poem, the wine felt doubly strong"

(3.) in "閑花爭兩岸", '閑'= 'free' (not owned); 閑花 means wild flower; 爭 is short for 爭豔(one-up each other in beauty)

> 閑花爭兩岸 means: " wild flowers on both shores abundantly bloom, as if they're competing against each other in beauty" (*to fight for people's attention*)

~

> 醉眼不朦朧 means: "even we are drunk, our eyes are not yet hazy (*we can still appreciate the beautiful scenery*)"

Answer (score 1):

I translated just for fun, 5 characters for 5 words:

共酌小亭下 sharing cups neath the canopy
詩新酒倍濃 new verse like potent wine
閑花爭兩岸 on both banks wafting flowers
醉眼不朦朧 our inebriated eyes perspicaciously perceive

Comment: Learned some new english words